# Pandas select rows where relative column values exist in DataFrame

Tags: pandas, selection, pandas-loc

Let's say you have a dataframe like this:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({
        'epoch_minute': [i for i in reversed(range(25090627,25635267))],
        'count': [random.randint(11, 35) for _ in range(25090627,25635267)]})
>>> df.head()
   epoch_minute  count
0      25635266     12
1      25635265     20
2      25635264     33
3      25635263     11
4      25635262     35
```

and some relative epoch minute deltas like this:

```
day = 1440
week = 10080
month = 302400
```

How do I accomplish the equivalent of this code block:

```
for i,r in df.iterrows():
    if r['epoch_minute'] - day in df['epoch_minute'].values and \
            r['epoch_minute'] - week in df['epoch_minute'].values and \
            r['epoch_minute'] - month in df['epoch_minute'].values:
        # do stuff
```

using this syntax:

```
valid_rows = df.loc[(df['epoch_minute'] == df['epoch_minute'] - day) &
                    (df['epoch_minute'] == df['epoch_minute'] - week) &
                    (df['epoch_minute'] == df['epoch_minute'] - month]
```

I understand why the `loc` select doesn't work, but I'm just asking if there exists a more elegant way to select the valid rows without iterating through the rows of the dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add parentheses and `&` for `bitwise AND` with [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) for check membership:

```
valid_rows = df[(df['epoch_minute'].isin(df['epoch_minute'] - day)) &
                (df['epoch_minute'].isin(df['epoch_minute'] - week)) &
                (df['epoch_minute'].isin(df['epoch_minute'] - month))]
```

---

```
valid_rows = df[((df['epoch_minute'] - day).isin(df['epoch_minute'])) &
                ((df['epoch_minute']- week).isin(df['epoch_minute'] )) &
                ((df['epoch_minute'] - month).isin(df['epoch_minute']))]
```

Comment: Ah yes, you're right about the syntax -- but `valid_rows` is still empty after executing either of these `loc` selections whereas the for loop produces correctly identifies 242240 valid rows.

Comment: Shouldn't the arguments of `isin` and the value it's called on be switched like this: (df['epoch_minute'] - day).isin(df['epoch_minute']) & ... ?

Comment: @aweeeezy - I test it and get same output, but added to answer.